# Sublist by boolean pattern

Tags: haskell

I need to extract from a list elements in the odd positions. In the Data.List library I found anything about. So I created the following functions. I would like to know if there is a library that contains this functions and other similar and if it is possible to refactor my functions significantly. Thanks.

```
extractByPattern p l = extractByPatternRaw bp l
  where
  bp = map (== 't') p

extractByPatternRaw p l = foldr  select [] coupledList
  where
  coupledList = zip (concat . repeat $ p) l
  select (b,x) acc
   | b         = x : acc
   | otherwise = acc

oddPos = extractByPattern "tf"
-- ex. oddPos [1..20] == [1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19]

everyTwoAndFivePos = extractByPattern "ftfft"
-- ex. everyTwoAndFivePos [1..20] == [2,5,7,10,12,15,17,20]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an alternative:

```
λ map fst $ filter snd $ zip [1..20] $ cycle . map (== 't') $ "ftfft"
[2,5,7,10,12,15,17,20]
```

So you could do something like the following:

```
extractByPattern pattern list = map fst $ filter snd $ zip list $ cycle . map (== 't') $ pattern
```

---

Nothing jumps out in Hoogle for [`[Bool] -> [a] -> [a]`](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%5BBool%5D+-%3E+%5Ba%5D+-%3E+%5Ba%5D) or [`[a] -> [Bool] -> [a]`](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%5Ba%5D+-%3E+%5BBool%5D+-%3E+%5Ba%5D), which would save the `zip`-`filter`-`snd`-`map`-`fst` hoop-jumping.

Comment: This is one of the cases where a list comprehension is, at least from my point of view, easier to read: `extractByPattern pattern list = [i | (i,t) <- zip list (cycle pattern), t == 't']`

Comment: @Zeta Your solution is very elegant

Comment: @Zeta: `[i | (i, 't') <- zip list (cycle pattern)]` works too.

Comment: @AndrásKovács It is even better!